# cshtml - accessing table elements and manipulating table rows

Tags: javascript, html

How can I clear the records of a HTML table , if a particular column contains duplicate entries? e.g If I have 2 columns in a table -  Name and age, if 2 people have the same age , then delete the second row completely.

```
 function DeleteDuplicate() {
        // FIRSTLY FIND THE ROWS TO DELETE
        var data = document.getElementById("CommitTable");
        var unique_data_Array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.rows.length; i++) {
            unique_data_Array.push(data.rows[i])
        }
        debugger
        var g = 0; m = 0; u = 0;4
        for (var j = 0; j < unique_data_Array.length; j++)
         {
             if (unique_data_Array[j][0] =  "*group*")
             {
                g++;
                if (g > 1) 
                {debugger
                    //                    delete data.rows(j);
                    data.deleteRow(j);   
                }
            }
            else if (unique_data_Array[j][0] = "*member*") 
            {
                m++;
                if (m > 1)
                 {
                debugger
                    //                    delete data.rows(j);
                data.deleteRow(j);

                }
            }
        }
    }
                    window.onload = DeleteDuplicate;
```

This is my code in the javascript , For all the rows which contain group, or member in the first column, I want to keep just one row and delete the others.

It is throwing an error in the statement  data.deleteRow(j); invalid index

Comment: You mean same `age` and `name`?

Comment: No , just the same age. It should keep only one record for all the people of a particular age , delete the others.

Comment: I can compare 2 records by their id's but I don't know how to delete records

Comment: also, deleteROw should contain round brackets only , right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code does exactly want you want to:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function data_collect(){

    var data= document.getElementById("my_table");
    var coll_Array=[];
    var int_Array=[];

    for(var i=0;i<data.rows.length;i++){
       for(var j=0;j<data.rows[i].cells.length;j++){
          int_Array.push(data.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML);
       }
       coll_Array.push(int_Array);
       int_Array=[];
    }
    return coll_Array;   
}  

function delRow(){
    var table_row_data=data_collect();
    var unique_Array=table_row_data[0];
    var index_Array=[];
    for (var i=1;i<table_row_data.length;i++){
        var criteria=table_row_data[i].every(
              function(x){return unique_Array.indexOf(x)==-1;});
        if (criteria==true){
            unique_Array.concat(table_row_data[i]);
        }
        else{
        index_Array.push(i);
        }
    }
    for (var j=0;j<index_Array.length;j++){
  document.getElementById("my_table").deleteRow(index_Array[j]);
    }
}



</script>
</head>


<body>
<table id="my_table">
<tr>
<td>Ram</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Chris</td>
<td>26</td>
</tr>
<td>Kevin</td>
<td>25</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button onclick="delRow()">Click me</button>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Can you just do the console output for record_to_delete array and see if it has correct index of rows to delete?

Comment: it is showing an error "invalid argument' but the argument is correct , I wanted to delete the 4th row , the argument is 3(as the index starts from 0) , what's the issue?

Comment: Correct me if I have properly not understood you: You are saying that record_to_delete array in above code has right indexes of the rows you want to delete from table but it fails to delete. Is that right?

Comment: Are you sure that you can copied my code in a right way? Look closely to me code and you will see that the loop: for (var i=0; i<data.rows.length;i++) extends upto the bottom EXCLUDING the bottom-most loop. Your uses of braces are incorrect. Pay attention to where braces begins and ends for each loop and see if you see the result. If not, comment back.

Comment: well , the first loop just populates the unique_data_Array so the loop closes there , then I am going after the first column of the unique_data_Array , n if group or member occurs more than once , I am deleting the 2nd row.

Comment: hey ! I got one correction,instead of my unique_data_Array.length; in the second forloop , I should have data.row.count,now it is not throwing any error but deleting the wrong rows.

Comment: Check my answer again. I tried it by creating simple table and it works if I have understood you properly.